# ng-show always false for angularJS spa

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is a snippet from my index.html

```
<div class="My-Title" ng-show="isHomePage()">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2 class="My-Title-Title">My Title</h2>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 text-container">Some text about the business</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without ng-show it appears on each page of the site. The goal is to just have it show just for '/'  however all I am getting is div.My-Title.ng-hide when looking at the dev tools and nothing showing on the page.

The relevant snippets from the app.js

```
module.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    document.title = $route.current.title;
    });
}]);
.
.
.
angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isHomePage = function() {
       return $location.path() === '/';
    };
});
.
.
.
$routeProvider.when( '/', {
   templateUrl: '/partials/site/index.html',
   controller: 'noticeController',
   title: "business title"
```

Tested various different isHomePage functions. Must be something simple I'm missing!

Comment: Did you try logging `$location.path()` to see if it's indeed `"/"` as you expect?

Comment: Yes, I tried including `console.log("$location.path: ", $location.path());` but see nothing in the devtools console.

Comment: That's inside of the `isHomePage` function body? It seems impossible that `ng-show` is never calling it, assuming there's no filtering in your devtools console. Can you share a full, runnable [mcve]? You can make AngularJS [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: I shall setup the stack snippet over the weekend. Ty